# In Isaiah 28:16 what does it mean that the cornerstone is "tested"?

Tags: isaiah

> [Isa 28:16 NIV] (16) So this is what the Sovereign LORD says: "See, I lay a stone in Zion, **a tested stone**, a precious cornerstone for a sure foundation; the one who relies on it will never be stricken with panic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In Isaiah 28:16 what does it mean that the cornerstone is “tested”?**

> [Isa 28:16 NIV] (16) So this is what the Sovereign LORD says: "See, I
>   lay a stone in Zion, a tested stone, a precious cornerstone for a sure
>   foundation; the one who relies on it will never be stricken with
>   panic.

The Apostle Peter, by quoting Isaiah's words, showed that the prophecy applied to Jesus,  " a precious corner stone" Peter wrote:

1 Peter 2:4-7 (NET Bible)

**A Living Stone, a Chosen People**

> 4 "So as you come to him, a living stone rejected by men but[b] chosen
>   and precious[c] in God’s sight, 5 you yourselves, as living stones,
>   are built up as a spiritual house to be a holy priesthood and to offer
>   spiritual sacrifices that are acceptable to God through Jesus Christ.
>   6 For it says in scripture, “Look, I lay in Zion a stone, a chosen and
>   precious cornerstone, and whoever believes in him will never be put to
>   shame.” 7 So you who believe see  his value, but for those who do not
>   believe, the stone that the builders rejected has become the
>   cornerstone."

**How was Jesus tried and tested cornerstone?**

I lay a stone in Zion, a tested cornerstone, Jesus was that precious cornerstone chosen by God to be the foundation of his city, for three and a half years he was tested to the utmost, in all matter of trials ,temptations, persecutions, and even nailed to  death. In all his trials He remained  obedient and faithful to the end, never going contrary to his Father's will, He loved  his  Father to the end. Being tested  in the flesh the quality of his faith was hardened  and proven something  altogether different to being faithful in heaven.

**The scriptures record his trials:**

Hebrews 2:18  (NASB)

> 18 "For since He Himself was tempted in that which He has suffered, He
>   is able to come to the aid of those who are tempted."

Hebrews 4:15  (NASB)

> 15 "For we do not have a high priest who cannot sympathize with our
>   weaknesses, but One who has been tempted in all things as we are, yet
>   without sin."

Hebrews 5:7-8  (NASB)

> 7 "In the days of His flesh, [b]He offered up both prayers and
>   supplications with loud crying and tears to the One able to save Him
>   from death, and He was heard because of His piety. 8 Although He was a
>   Son, He learned obedience from the things which He suffered."

Revelation 3:14  (NASB)

> 14 “To the angel of the church in Laodicea write: The Amen, the
>   faithful and true Witness, the Beginning of the creation of God, says
>   this:

1 Timothy 6:13  (NASB)

> 13 "I charge you in the presence of God, who gives life to all things,
>   and of Christ Jesus, who testified the good confession before Pontius
>   Pilate."

Jesus Christ resisted every attempt to break down his integrity, he endured all trials and continued faithfully on regardless of the opposition of sinners against him.The apostle John also uttered prophecy covering Zion many years after the literal Zion was destroyed. John  wrote ,Rev. 14:1(NASB)

The Lamb and the 144,000 on Mount Zion

> 14 "Then I looked, and behold, the Lamb was standing on Mount Zion,
>   and with Him one hundred and forty-four thousand, having His name and
>   the name of His Father."

Comment: Jesus was not 'nailed to death'. He gave up his own life, voluntarily. _No man taketh it from me, but I lay it down of myself._ John 10:18. Apart from that . . . +1.

Comment: @Nigel J: Your so right Nigel. The Father displayed his love for the self-sacrificing “fine shepherd” by raising him from the dead on the third day. John 10:17